# Folder in views

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Can you help me understand how can I have access to my folder in "*views*"?

In my "*views*" folder I have:

- *home.ejs*
- *cases.ejs*
- *about.ejs*
- *Solutions* folder.

In "*Solutions*" folder I have:

- *solution1.ejs*
- *solution2.ejs*.

For *home.ejs*, *cases.ejs*, *about.ejs* I can render pages in this way:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home")
});

app.get("/cases", function(req, res){
    res.render("cases");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.render("about");
});
```

Now my question is: how can I render *solution1.ejs* and *solution2.ejs* which are in "*Solutions*" folder?

Comment: Do you have `solutions` folder inside view ?

Comment: Yes. I wrote in my question that I have "Solution" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render with

```
res.render('./solutions/solutions1')
```